# How to draw graph in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new ,and I don't understand why this method when copied to windows forms doesn't do anything when running the program. I was copy it from MSDN page.

```
public void DrawLinesPoint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            // Create pen.
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

            // Create array of points that define lines to draw.
            Point[] points =
                     {
                 new Point(10,  10),
                 new Point(10, 100),
                 new Point(200,  50),
                 new Point(250, 300)
             };

            //Draw lines to screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points);
        }
```

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know that works or you need more help to understand

Comment: Go to the event pane of the properties window of the control or form you want to paint on and doubleclick the Paint event ! There write `DrawLinesPoint(e);`. Also: change `Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);` to `using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3)){....your drawing code here...}` - You should have found this on the MSDN page; but MSDN is not always the best source..

Comment: @Clint all ok . I understood it !

Comment: @Koeno, that's great, if the answer has helped, you can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typically, when you draw on a form, you handle the form’s `Paint event` and perform the drawing using the `Graphics` property of the `PaintEventArgs`**

*In your code you need to add the `DrawLinesPoint` to the paint event before being able to use it*

In your `Constructor()` add

```
InitializeComponent();
this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.DrawLinesPoint);
```

And in your `Paint` PaintEventHandler

```
private void DrawLinesPoint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3);

    // Create array of points that define lines to draw.
    Point[] points =
                {
            new Point(10,  10),
            new Point(10, 100),
            new Point(200,  50),
            new Point(250, 300)
        };

    //Draw lines to screen.
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(pen, points);
}
```

Comment: While solving the issue I would not recommend adding the event handling here. It really belongs where the designer would have put it. So I recommend going to the event pane of the properties window of the control or form you want to paint on and doubleclicking the Paint event !